# puppeteer cannot control 3rd tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to have my puppeteer script open 4 tabs each going to a different url.  What I have encountered is that I can have the script successfully control the first 2 tabs opened in my chrome driver.  However, whenever it gets to the 3rd tab, I get an error saying

> "(node:8141) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of
>   undefined (node:8141) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code."

```
let pages = await browser.pages();
const p1 = 'https://www.page.com/tab1';
const p2 = 'https://www.page.com/tab2';
const p3 = 'https://www.page.com/tab3';
const p4 = 'https://www.page.com/tab4';
const ptest = 'https://www.test.com';


    await browser.newPage();
    await browser.newPage();
    await browser.newPage();
    await browser.newPage();

    await pages[0].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
    await pages[1].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
    await pages[2].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
    await pages[3].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

The error is thrown because [browser.pages()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserpages) resolves to an array of all currently open pages. If we look at it line by line, what happens is the following (assuming you start with a "fresh" browser):

```js
let pages = await browser.pages();
```

`pages` now is an array with one page (the default blank page after the browser is started).

```js
await browser.newPage();
await browser.newPage();
await browser.newPage();
await browser.newPage();
```

You create four new pages, but this does not automatically update your `pages` array. `pages` still contains only one page.

```js
await pages[0].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

The first call works as `pages[0]` contains a page.

```js
await pages[1].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

This will throw an error (`Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined`) as `pages[1]` is undefined.

#### Fix (and code improvement)

Move your line `let pages = await browser.pages();` down in your code to be called before you use the pages. To improve your code you can also remove one `browser.newPage()` call, as one page is already present (right now you actually have five open pages) and to speed up your code you can use `Promise.all`:

```js
const p1 = 'https://www.page.com/tab1';
const p2 = 'https://www.page.com/tab2';
const p3 = 'https://www.page.com/tab3';
const p4 = 'https://www.page.com/tab4';
const ptest = 'https://www.test.com';

await Promise.all([ // opens all pages at once
    browser.newPage(),
    browser.newPage(),
    browser.newPage(),
]);

let pages = await browser.pages(); // now resolves with four pages

await pages[0].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
await pages[1].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
await pages[2].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
await pages[3].goto(p1, {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

Answer (score 0):

these issue is might be because of http errors or browse version. please check below link those may help you

If it's http error try,

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
```

or if it's related to browser check this post
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1182